# How to count/flatten inner list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to count amount of elements in inner list.
I have object, which looks like that

```
{
    "author": [
        {
            "author_id": "1",
            "author_name": "King",
            "languages": [
                {
                    "language": "EN",
                    "books": [
                        {
                            "book_id": "111"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "222"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "333"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "444"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "555"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "language": "CZ",
                    "books": [
                        {
                            "book_id": "123"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "45"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "67"
                        },
                        {
                            "book_id": "89"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so lets assume there is only one `Author`, so it is ok `author = authorList[0]`, and I want to count amount of books he has in above object. So this author has 5 books assigned to language `EN` and 4 books for `CZ` what gives us 9 books.

I was trying to use `reduce` function, which will return flatter list of only books and after that I can just use `len(books)`.
But `list(reduce(lambda x, y: x["books"] + y["books"], author["languages"]))` returns `["language", "books"]` as a result, so clearly not what I want.

Any help?

I know I can use nester for loops but I would like to use different apporach.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `jmespath` then you can get it like

```
import jmespath
print(len(jmespath.search("author[*].languages[*].books[][]", data)))

#also if you want to filter on the basis of author_id

print(len(jmespath.search("author[?author_id=='1'].languages[*].books[][]", data)))
```

##### Also your code is working fine

```
author = data["author"][0]
print(list(reduce(lambda x, y: x["books"] + y["books"], author["languages"])))
#[{'book_id': '111'}, {'book_id': '222'}, {'book_id': '333'}, {'book_id': '444'}, {'book_id': '555'}, {'book_id': '123'}, {'book_id': '45'}, {'book_id': '67'}, {'book_id': '89'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hacky, but how about `str(author_dict).count('book_id')`?
It assumes the book IDs are unique though.